# Add example value to swagger UI for parameters

Tags: .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

Is there any way in .Net core to include Example value to parameter of an action method in the Swagger UI. The same way the example value is displayed for response/request.

There doesn't seem any direct way such as `SwaggerRequestExample` in `.Net core` so that example value can be displayed for Parameters.

Can someone help me with initial solution or any link with which I can start.

I am looking for output something like below.

[image]

This is model object

```
public class Vehicle
{
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string VehicleName { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

This is post method

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void Post(int id, [FromBody] Vehicle val)
 {

 }
```

This would display ID as a parameter but Vehicle model doesn't show up in Parameters list. I want it to display as an example value. I have also configured following in startup file
`c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);`

Comment: Can you include your code showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: @NicholasRees I have edited the question to include code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Swashbuckle generates and exposes Swagger JSON in version `3.0` of the specification—officially called the `OpenAPI` Specification. To support backwards compatibility, you can opt into exposing JSON in the `2.0` format instead. This `2.0` format is important for integrations such as Microsoft Power Apps and Microsoft Flow that currently support OpenAPI version `2.0`. To opt into the `2.0` format, set the `SerializeAsV2` property in Startup.Configure:

```
   ...
   // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
    });
  ...
```

**Before**

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "SwaggerApplication",
    "version": "1.0"
  },...
```

[image]

**After**

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "SwaggerApplication",
    "version": "1.0"
  }, ...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the answer.  Yes I can do this, but I need this 'example value' in the Parameters description. I have added the link in the question how it should display.

Comment: @Soft_API_Dev,  I understand what  you mean now, you need version `2.0` UI not `3.0`, you could opt into the 2.0 format as above and test result has been posted for u.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It worked! Thanks